# Is "import"-ing data pythonic?

Tags: python, import

I have a python script that, in it's "initialize" runmode, accesses multiple files on my system and assembles what it thinks is the correct data. This data needs to be reviewed by a user before setting the script to run in "final" mode, when the data is actually used.

Right now I'm writing out the data to be reviewed into a data.py file, in the form of python data structures, e.g. the contents of data.py could be:

```
data1 = "script_generated_filename_1"

data2 = [ "script_generated_date1",
          "script_generated_date2" ]
```

After the user validates the data.py file, the "final" runmode then uses an "import data" call to gain access to the data, via data.data1, data.data2, etc...

I've been trying to clean up my python programming style, and come more in line with what is generally considered to be pythonic. After reading through the [module](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) docs, I have my doubts as to whether using the import function in this way is pythonic, or if there is a more mainstream way to accomplish this type of user-validation using python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fine thing to do with a module.  The thing you want to avoid is executing code that does too much, or has side-effects, at import time, and this doesn't do that.

Comment: So true. This nice thing about initializing data in the body of a module is that you're free to change it later -- say to reading (and possibly parsing) an external file instead of using Python literals as the OP has in his examples. Another feature is that this automatically only happens once the first time the module is `imprted`ed.

Comment: @martineau: interesting perspective.  I'd say reading a file at import-time is a no-no!

Comment: The only concern would be size.  I did this once and created a module with 42,000 lines of code.   A bit slow to import.  But it ran really fast once it was imported.  And it had a delightfully simple API.  `import the_big_dataset; the_big_dataset.lookup[some_key]`.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: What exactly do you have against reading a file at import-time?

Comment: @S.Lott: Wouldn't the module be turned into a .pyc file after it was imported for the first time (and all 42K lines not need to be read again when import again later)?

Comment: @martineau: It still takes (relatively) forever to load.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should put your data in text files (JSON, CSV, whatever is appropriate) and then just have your script read it in. In general (not just in Python), it's best to keep code and data separate.

Comment: This isn't always True.  Parse overhead, not to mention writing and maintaining parser code, is a cost that must be weighed vs. perceived and real benefits of storing this data in text files.

Comment: @dorkitude: Writing your own parser would be overkill, true. But for many viable data format choices, there are parsers and serializers in the standard library, and for others there are widely-used and maintained open source libraries. And parse overhead should be negible for *initialization* code.

Comment: @delnan: You're right, but that doesn't mean it should be unilaterally discarded as an option.

I also wanted to state that JSON isn't particularly more convenient than Python's primitives (in fact, I'd argue that it's less convenient due to its issues with trailing commas).

Finally, using Python for your data has the added benefit of catching data formatting errors at compile time instead of runtime.

Comment: @dorkitude: But I'm not saying it shouldn't be considered. I'm just playing devil's advocate and debunking weak arguments.

Comment: I mostly took issue with the statement "it's best to keep code and data separate".  This is a rather complicated issue, and IMHO a blanket statement like that reveals the need for more consideration.

Comment: I'm not so sure my mention of parse overhead is a weak argument.  While parsing the JSON equivalent of the sample data in the OP is indeed negligible, it would add a (in my estimation needless) cost that is quite substantial, if we were dealing with large data sets.

Comment: @dorkitude: I think you're misinterpreting my post (or maybe my post was too ambiguous). I said "In general, it's best to", not "As an absolute rule, you must". There are always edge cases, but it's almost always best to keep your data and code separate.

Comment: @dorkitude: "Finally, using Python for your data has the added benefit of catching data formatting errors at compile time instead of runtime." This isn't really a benefit in this case, because either the module will be compiled at basically the same point that a config file would have been parsed anyway, or else the user's life is made more complicated - i.e. we incur the downside of *adding a concept of compile-time* where there wasn't one before :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing un-pythonic about your code: You're properly importing namespaces and referring to them and you're treating the module as the unit of reuse.

There may be a more elegant solution, and if you can post more specific details about the problem domain, we can probably help you with that.  But elegance must often be offset with economy.

My pragmatic view is that if you're not repeating yourself, and you're not breaking any major conventions, and your code works, then you're in the right:  Even if the design is flawed, a good design can always be later imposed upon a flawed design that's DRY ;)